# Use custom URL in IISExpress as Base URL

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I have a project which uses IISExpress.
Let say the name of the website project is: AdventureWorks

When I run the application in my VS, it will go to http://localhost:12345/

But I wanted it to use the website project as the base URL, so for example: http://localhost:12345/AdventureWorks

I tried setting up in project Property Pages > Server > User custom server > Base URL : http://localhost:12345/AdventureWorks

But it does not seem to work. I get the following error message:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to add that URL for the local run? Any reason?

Comment: Because there is some pre-set up callback that will call http://localhost:12345/AdventureWorks, which I can't change. So I have to set up my site to use the base URL accordingly.

Comment: Let's say on iis there's a website where you wanna publish this project so that website nane is AdventureWorks. Is it like that?

Comment: Yes. But the thing is I use IISExpress and I'm not so sure where to force it to use this URL for my application. Basically now all the files are mapped to localhost:12345, e.g. `localhost:12345/Default.aspx`, which I don't want.

Comment: does your app runs *without debugging*?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I see that the custom server option requires IIS (not IISExpress), and I just uninstalled IIS since I'll be using IISExpress. So I guess the problem relies on something else.

Comment: Meaning to say that I have to configure it in some other way rather than custom server option.

Comment: if your app runs *without debugging* on your custom URL then you can later **attach to process**

Comment: I think that's not an approach that I wanted. I need to be able to use with or without debugging. I'm exploring the applicationhost.config now if I can see any improvement

Comment: I wish this was easier; this can highlight bugs in Javascript where relative paths are incorrectly used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some workaround by editing the `applicationhost.config`. There are 2 types of `applicationhost.config` here, one is in `C:\Users\[Username]\Documents\IISExpress\config` and the one inside the project `.vs\config`. Apparently, `.vs\config` was used in this solution and I added:

```
<virtualDirectory path="/AdventureWorks" physicalPath="D:\Codes\AdventureWorks\trunk\Project\AdventureWorks" />
```

So that it will map the location of `AdventureWorks` too.